# Is there a visual tool to view a RavenDB database?

Tags: ravendb

I just got RavenDB to work.
I realised I have to start RavenDB\packages\RavenDB.1.0.573\server.exe to access it in my application via:

```
    DocumentStore store = new DocumentStore()
    {
        Url = "http://localhost:8080"
    };

    store.Initialize();
```

Is there a tool to view the data in the database similar to SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run the server and access it using the browser, you'll get the buil-in RavenDB management Studio

http://ravendb.net/docs/intro/basic-concepts#the-management-studio

Answer (score 8):

There are two products at the time of this answer

1. The built in web browser, as @synhershko answered.
2. [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) with the RavenDb driver.